# Open Ruy Lopez for Black

Tags: opening, ruy-lopez

Why there are no good videos on Open Ruy Lopez for Black? Is the variation too bad for Black? There are lots of videos from the White side, but I did not find any good videos from the black side; why is it so?

Comment: Did you manage to find any videos or games showing ruy lopez played as black? Or is it not advisable to play ruy lopez when playing black?

Comment: There are no good videos because most people do not know how to make a good video, and even fewer know how to create useful content to be made into a video. YouTube is full of hogwash videos in which you can’t see what is going on and/or can’t hear what they are saying clearly. Bad videos are the norm for wannabee amateur video makers, too many of which own a cell phone that can capture video.

Comment: This answer is CORRECT. It answers the OP question exactly, which was << Why there are no good videos on Open Ruy Lopez for Black? >> There are no good videos because most people do not know how to make a good video, and even fewer know how to create useful content to be made into a video. And even fewer of those know how to play chess well. YouTube is full of hogwash videos in which you can’t see what is going on and/or can’t hear what they are saying clearly. Bad videos are the norm for wannabee amateur video makers, too many of which own a cell phone that can capture video. Rewan needs to b

Comment: @edwinaoliver If you read past the first sentence of the post, you will realize that OP is asking why videos exist explaining the variation from White's point of view, while videos explaining the variation from Black's point of view don't seem to exist in as large a quantity. Your answer does not adress this apparent disparity in the slightest; while it is true that many videos are made by amateurs that do not really know what they're doing, this does not really explain why the opening is covered way more from one side's point of view than the other.

Comment: yes. he asks two questions.  I answered the first one.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you looking for video?  How about looking for a game? Checkout chessgames.com then search for Open Ruy Lopez ECO code to look for games won by black. It will show you how black piece should play against open Ruy Lopez

Comment: Not necessarily. You'll often see games there where Black tried bad ideas as well. I agree that only looking for videos is limiting, but you'd at least want something that is intentionally an educational resource.

Comment: The problem with chessgames.com is that there are no latest games.And mostly the premium members have all the good things..are there any other sources.I dont want database site...and site which will guide me like telling all the plans of Black in open lopez